# Mimic a phone book

Tags: python

I am trying to create a code that mimics a phone book.
I want the program to accept a last name, a first name or a phone number from the user and to read through the text file/list, looking for a match.  If match(s) are found, display the information, and then redisplay the menu.
 If the entry was not found display the appropriate not found message.  All search results will be written to the screen.

```
def main():

    firstname=[]
    lastname=[]
    phone=[]

    loadLists(firstname, lastname, phone)
    choice = menu()

    while choice != '4':
        if choice == '1':
            getLastName(firstname, lastname, phone)
        elif choice == '2':
            getFirstName(firstname, lastname, phone)
        elif choice == '3':
            getPhone(firstname, lastname, phone)

        choice = menu()

def loadLists(firstname, lastname, phone):

    myFile="entries.txt"
    fileInput=open(myFile)
    count = 0

    for myString in fileInput:
        myString = myString.strip()
        myString = myString.lower()
        myNum = count % 3
        if myNum == 0:
            lastname.append(myString)
        elif myNum == 1:
            firstname.append(myString)
        elif myNum == 2:
            phone.append(myString)
        count = count +1

    fileInput.close()


def menu():
    option = '0'
    while option != '1' and option != '2' and option != '3' and option != '4':
        print("\n1. Look up contact by last name")
        print("2. Look up contact by first name")
        print("3. Look up contact by phone number")
        print("4. Quit")

        option = input("\nMenu option: ")
        if option != '1' and option != '2' and option != '3' and option != '4':
            print("Invalid option. Please select again.")
    return option


def getLastName(firstname, lastname, phone):
    target=input("\nEnter contacts last name: ")
    target=target.strip().lower()
    position=0

    if target in lastname:
        while True:
            try:
                position=lastname.index(target, position)
                entry =firstname[position].title()+" "+lastname[position].title()+" "+phone[position].title()
                print("\n" + entry)
                position= position + 1
            except:
                break
    else:
        print("\nNot found")


def getFirstName(firstname, lastname, phone):
    target=input("\nEnter contacts first name: ")
    target=target.strip().lower()
    position=0
    if target in firstname:
        while True:
            try:
                position=firstname.index(target, position)
                entry=firstname[position].title()+" "+lastname[position].title()+" "+phone[position].title()
                print("\n" + entry)
                position= position + 1
            except:
                break
    else:
        print("\nNot found")


def getPhone(firstname, lastname, phone):
    target=input("\nEnter contacts phone number: ")
    target=target.strip().lower()
    position=0
    if target in phone:
        while True:
            try:
                position=phone.index(target, position)
                entry=firstname[position].title()+" "+lastname[position].title()+" "+phone[position].title()
                print("\n" + entry)
                position=position + 1
            except:
                break
    else:
        print("\nNot found")


main()
```

When I run the program it won't load the file I have assigned 'entries.txt'. Could someone explain to me why? I have the file saved to my computer as 'entries' and i've double checked that it is a txt file.

Comment: Is entries in the same folder as your program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
def loadLists(firstname, lastname, phone):

    myFile="entries.txt"
    fileInput=open(myFile)
    count = 0
```

Try using:

```
def loadLists(firstname, lastname, phone):

    myFile="entries.txt"
    fileInput=open(myFile, "r")
    count = 0
```

Comment: Glad I could help a fellow Jenna :)

Answer (score 1):

You're not even getting into the loop in `loadList`, since `fileInput`is a pointer to a file. Try `for myString in fileInput.readlines():` instead.